# A. Find the height of the mountain; B. Find the distance to the nearest kilometre stone

Tags: trigonometry

From the top of a mountain, in the same vertical plane is two consecutive kilometers stones on the level piece of ground the angles of depression to the kilometer stones are 42° 12 minutes and 23° 30 minutes respectively.

A. Calculate the hate of the mountain
B.  Calculate the distance to the nearest kilometre stone

Comment: "height" not hate.

Answer (score 0):

Denote $\alpha = 42^{\circ}12'$, $\beta = 23^{\circ}30'$.

 $h - $ height; $d - $ distance to nearest km stone.

Then
$$\tan \alpha = \dfrac{h}{d}; \tag{1}$$
$$\tan \beta = \dfrac{h}{d+1}. \tag{2}$$
So :
$$
\dfrac{\tan\alpha}{\tan\beta} = \dfrac{h/d}{h/(d+1)}=\dfrac{d+1}{d} =1+\dfrac{1}{d}.
$$

And therefore
$$
d = \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{\tan\alpha}{\tan\beta} - 1}=\dfrac{\tan\beta}{\tan\alpha-\tan\beta}.\tag{3}
$$

Then $h$ can be found easily from $(1), (3)$.

Comment: Thank you very much Oleg

Comment: @NaftaliPNAShikongo If Oleg's answer was helpful, please upvote or accept it by clicking the up arrow or the checkmark, respectively, near the upper-left corner of the answer.